# Intereceptor for REST API Camel

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

In the camelcontext APIs are defined in the format <camel:from uri="rest:post:aaa>
How can I write a common intereceptor for all the API REST request?

Comment: use interceptFrom and specify a pattern. Assuming you go to a direct straight afterwards. So interceptFrom uri="direct:rest*"

Answer (score 1):

Camel supports three kinds of interceptors:

1. intercept that intercepts each and every processing step while
   routing an Exchange in the route.
2. interceptFrom(String uri) that intercepts incoming Exchange in the route.
3. interceptSendToEndpoint that intercepts when an Exchange is about to
   be sent to the given Endpoint.

There are several ways you can write interceptors for camel:

```
class CustomInterceptingRoute extends CustomRouteBuilder{
        void configure() {
            interceptFrom('rest:*')...
        }
    }
```